# Minimum rightmost list element in python

Tags: python-2.7, list

In a list of numbers, `n = [5,9,3,4,7,3,5,6,7]` I want the index of the rightmost minimum value in python.

There are functions in numpy for minimum value like: `numpy.argmin(n)` will return 2, but I want a function that will return 5. Is there a more elegant way other than

`(len(n) - 1) - numpy.argmin(n[::-1])`?

Or is there no builtin function to get the rightmost minimum index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the indexes of minimum items. then return the largest index. This way it makes more sense logically. But you would have to call `np.array` to get a `ndarray` first

```
n = [5,9,3,4,7,3,5,6,7]
a = np.array([5,9,3,4,7,3,5,6,7]) 
minItemWithMaxIndex = np.where(a == a.min())[0].max()
```

Comment: Thanks, I was struggling to come up with a more readable solution.